# SQL query to join rows with same values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I've come across a problem that I don't really know how to solve.
I have a table which looks somewhat like this:

```
ID   Name     Price     Quantity
1    BookA      5         10
2    BookB     10         15
3    BookA     15         15
4    BookA      5         25
```

How could I join rows which have same Name, same Price and sum Quantity? So it would look like this:

```
ID   Name     Price     Quantity
1    BookA      5         35
2    BookB     10         15
3    BookA     15         15
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT Min(ID), Name, Price, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Name, Price;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you, Sir